# Hyphenation in New Environment

Tags: hyphenation

I have defined a new environment for my bibliography (long story short, I have to submit soon and do not have the time for bibdesk managing etc.):

```
\newenvironment{literatur}{%
    \parskip6pt \parindent0pt \raggedright
    \def\lititem{\hangindent=0.5cm \hangafter1}}{%
    \par\ignorespaces} %damit wird der hängende Einzug für das Literaturverzeichnis ermöglicht.
```

Problem: Within this environment there is no hyphenation anylonger. Does anybody know, how to solve this?

Comment: `\raggedright` suppresses hyphenation (almost) completely. You can load `\usepackage{ragged2e}` and use `\RaggedRight` instead.